# ROS2 : Rviz build failed : tf2_geometry_msgs issue

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,
while building the Rviz for for ROS2, getting below errors for tf2_geometry_msgs. I came to know that tf2 is not ported yet. Can anyone help with the compilation?

```
Starting >>> rviz_default_plugins
[Processing: rviz_default_plugins]
--- stderr: rviz_default_plugins
In file included from ~/ros2_rviz/build/rviz_default_plugins/include/rviz_default_plugins/transformation/../../../../../src/rviz/rviz_default_plugins/include/rviz_default_plugins/transformation/transformer_guard.hpp:43,
                 from ~/ros2_rviz/build/rviz_default_plugins/include/rviz_default_plugins/transformation/moc_transformer_guard.cpp:9:
~/ros2_rviz/src/rviz/rviz_default_plugins/include/rviz_default_plugins/transformation/tf_wrapper.hpp:40:10: fatal error: tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.hpp: No such file or directory
   40 | #include "tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rviz_default_plugins.dir/build.make:390: CMakeFiles/rviz_default_plugins.dir/include/rviz_default_plugins/transformation/moc_transformer_guard.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from ~/ros2_rviz/src/rviz/rviz_default_plugins/include/rviz_default_plugins/transformation/transformer_guard.hpp:43,
                 from ~/ros2_rviz/build/rviz_default_plugins/include/rviz_default_plugins/displays/laser_scan/../../../../../../src/rviz/rviz_default_plugins/include/rviz_default_plugins/displays/laser_scan/laser_scan_display.hpp:45,
                 from ~/ros2_rviz/build/rviz_default_plugins/include/rviz_default_plugins/displays/laser_scan/moc_laser_scan_display.cpp:9:
~/ros2_rviz/src/rviz/rviz_default_plugins/include/rviz_default_plugins/transformation/tf_wrapper.hpp:40:10: fatal error: tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.hpp: No such file or directory
   40 | #include "tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rviz_default_plugins.dir/build.make:338: CMakeFiles/rviz_default_plugins.dir/include/rviz_default_plugins/displays/laser_scan/moc_laser_scan_display.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1928: CMakeFiles/rviz_default_plugins.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< rviz_default_plugins [58.1s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 6 packages finished [1min 21s]
  1 package failed: rviz_default_plugins
  1 package had stderr output: rviz_default_plugins
  1 package not processed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384455/ros2-:-rviz-build-failed-:-tf2_geometry_msgs-issue/) by [baila](https://answers.ros.org/users/25509/baila/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2021-08-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on 2021-08-15**:
Which ROS version are you using, and did you install from binaries or source?
I saw the following from [rviz's README.md](https://github.com/ros2/rviz/blob/ros2/README.md)

```
Note: When building the current ros2 branch from source, the latest ROS 2 release for all dependencies might not be sufficient: it could be necessary to build the ROS 2 master branch. Make sure to have a source build of ROS 2 available (see installation procedure above).
```

**Comment by [baila](https://answers.ros.org/users/25509/baila/) on 2021-08-16**:
I installed ROS2 following https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Installation/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html

**Comment by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on 2021-08-16**:
Only suggestion I can think of, is to re-run rosdep, to make sure tf2_geometry_msgs gets installed correctly. It is listed as a dependency correctly in [package.xml of rviz](https://github.com/ros2/rviz/blob/60a7269a5b88266969fd24cf154f5b2c04a8ca6a/rviz_default_plugins/package.xml#L49).

Try running below, taken from this [step of installation procedure](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Installation/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html#install-dependencies-using-rosdep)

In your workspace,

```
rosdep update
```

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro rolling -y --skip-keys "console_bridge fastcdr fastrtps rti-connext-dds-5.3.1 urdfdom_headers"
```

And re-run the colcon build command.

**Comment by [baila](https://answers.ros.org/users/25509/baila/) on 2021-08-16**:
No success. Getting the same `tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.hpp` error even if the rosdep installation.

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro rolling -y --skip-keys "console_bridge fastcdr fastrtps rti-connext-dds-5.3.1 urdfdom_headers"
#All required rosdeps installed successfully
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue is resolved after following the steps from [Rviz Build](https://index.ros.org/r/rviz/). Do not do any modifications of path or anything. It will build cleanly.

---

Originally posted by [baila](https://answers.ros.org/users/25509/baila/) with karma: 32 on 2021-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) on 2021-08-19**:
Thank you for provide the solution!